# C# Do not add duplicated item in list that has same containing text

Tags: c#, file-io, duplicates

Hi I've made a program that has 2 lists, (urls, filteredUrls) the urls has duplicated stuff. filteredUrls
Is suppose to have urls's items without duplicated
Duplicated stuff Sample:

```
https://mysql-code.com/app.php?=
https://mysql-code.com/app.asp?=1
https://www.page.com/app=123
http://www.page.com/app=123+2
```

As you can see the mysql-code and page are duplicated, I did Distinct list for urls however It only remove items that is literally same, I want only to remove items that contains the same text only **Contains** exactly

My code

```cs
filteredUrls = urls.Distinct().ToList();
File.WriteAllLines(resFolder + @"\urls.txt", filteredUrls);
```

the file results output same text contains but different at end or start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To parse URL and get access to its components use [Uri Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=net-5.0).

Code below compare urls based on Host:

```cs
var urls = new[] {
    "https://mysql-code.com/app.php?=",
    "https://mysql-code.com/app.asp?=1",
    "https://www.page.com/app=123",
    "http://www.page.com/app=123+2"
};

var result = urls
    .Select(url => new Uri(url))
    .ToLookup(uri => uri.Host, uri => uri)
    .Select(v => v.First());

foreach (var uri in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(uri);
}

/*
https://mysql-code.com/app.php?=
https://www.page.com/app=123
*/
```

Comment: How do I write it to file?

Comment: Look at doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-write-text-to-a-file